# Word VBA - CompareDocuments - How to check Revisions object's contents

Tags: vba, ms-word

After comparing word documents with Application.CompareDocuments method, I need check all revisions found to keep only those 'real' text changes.
Thanks

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a code writing service. You should do some research, give something a go and then come back when you've hit a wall and ask a question that is a [mcve]. Happy Coding!

Answer (score 1):

So the soluition is to perform some check on the 'Text' property of each item belongs the Revision object.
The code is something like :

```
i = 1
While i <= ActiveDocument.Revisions.Count
    If ActiveDocument.Revisions.Item(i).Range.Text is text ...
    i = i + 1
...
Wend
```